# JavaFX TextField NuberFormatException

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

Have been sitting with this for over an hour, so I have a plain textField which is meant for entering Int numbers, and then I perform filtering based on the number.

My filter function

```
private void fillAllListsFiltered() {

        List<Trip> trips = tripHib.getAllTrips();
        trips.forEach(c -> { if(c.getTime() > gt(tripTextTime) && c.getLength() > gt(tripTextLength)) tripListView.getItems().add(c);});

    }
```

And then my "function" for parsing Int from the textField. (I understand I could just parse it in the first function as Integer.parseInt(tripTextTime.getText()), but for some reason it does not work.

```
private static int gt(TextField textField) {
        System.out.println(textField.getText());
        String text = textField.getText().trim();
        return Integer.parseInt(text);
    }
```

I have also added the trim as an extra, but it didn't really help.

the error is "NumberFormatException: For input string: "" "

Comment: It's telling you that the `TextField`'s text is blank (i.e., you're trying to parse `""` into an integer, which is obviously not possible). Are you passing the correct `TextField` instance to your method? Are you only calling this method at the correct time (i.e., after the user has actually entered something and wants to filter the data)? What should happen if the text field is blank? Perhaps that's a special case (e.g., don't filter by that attribute?).

Comment: The easiest way to handle this situation is to use TextFormatter with your TextField.  See my articles: https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/elements/textformatter/